# EAAccessory connected but not getting accessory objects sometime (iOS10.2)

Tags: bluetooth, xcode8, ios10, core-bluetooth, eaaccessory

I am facing a strange issue on iOS 10.2 version with my EAAccessory App. I have a headphone accessory, which I connect using Setting -> Bluetooth -> Headphone and Connect. 
After this, I launch my app, but I do not get the instance of accessory and not come to accessoryDidConnect: (Notification) a function of viewcontroller. 
Note: All other version it's working fine. but only 10.2 version,some times is working and some time not.
Please help me over same.

Comment: Have you found a resolution to this? What iOS device were you using?

Comment: Any solution for this? Struggling lot.